# SQLite: Conditional DDL Statements

Tags: sqlite, ddl

I wish to execute the following type of code in sqlite3:

```
drop table x if (select y from z where col1 = "a");
```

Essentially execute DDL commands IF certain values exist currently in the same database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, this is not possible without using external tools.

My solution for the moment is this:

```
PSEUDOCODE:
// create temp table;
// insert conditional DDL statement(s) into temp table along with an execute column
// run condition, and if valid, set temptable's corresponding row to execute 1;
// after condition is over, run all true statements in temp table
```

Answer (score 1):

A sqlite shell script:

```
.bail ON
SELECT CASE COUNT(*)
       WHEN 0       THEN 1/0  -- will throw
       ELSE 1
       END
  FROM z
 WHERE col1 = 'a';
DROP TABLE x;
```

Run it with `sqlite the_database < the_script`

Comment: That's a clever approach. Does it wind up looking like a failure on the console?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such syntax (see http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#drop-table-stmt)

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not give you a way to perform this function as a one-liner.
The closest you'll get to doing this in a single command is to:

1. issue: BEGIN TRANSACTION
2. perform the query: SELECT y FROM z WHERE col1 = "a"
3. DROP TABLE x
4. if (result from step 2 had >0 rows) 
       issue: COMMIT
   else
       issue: ROLLBACK